# How do you specify a date facet query in Solr?

Tags: solr

When I do a query to Solr, I get these facet_counts back:

```
'facet_counts' => {
    'facet_dates' => {
        'photo_added' => {
            '2009-12-28T18:00:00Z' => 396386,
            '2010-05-28T18:00:00Z' => 415370,
            'gap' => '+1MONTH',
            'end' => '2011-02-28T18:00:00Z',
        },
    },
},
```

However, when I add **any one** of these parameters to a `q=*:*` query:

```
fq=photo_added:2009-12-28T18:00:00Z
fq=photo_added:2009-12-28T18%3A00%3A00Z
```

I receive this as a response:

```
HTTP ERROR 400: Invalid Date String:'2009-12-28T18'
```

When I add **any one** of *these* parameters to a `q=*:*` query:

```
fq=photo_added:"2009-12-28T18:00:00Z"
fq=photo_added:"2009-12-28T18%3A00%3A00Z"
fq%3Dphoto_added%3A%222009-12-28T18%3A00%3A00Z%22
fq=photo_added%3A"2009-12-28T18%3A00%3A00Z"
```

I receive this in the response:

```
<result name="response" numFound="0" start="0"/>
```

But when I don't have an `fq=` constraint on my query, I get `numFound="8001000"`, so it's definitely something wrong with the `fq=` constraint.

**How can I do a date facet query that works?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're misinterpreting the date facet results. IIRC, since you defined a gap of 1 month, the result `'2009-12-28T18:00:00Z' => 396386` means that between 2009-12-28T18:00:00Z and 2010-01-28T18:00:00Z (one month) there are 396386 results.

But then you're running a filter query with an *exact* date, and you get no results because no document matches *exactly* that date and time. If you want to fetch those 396386 documents, run a filter query with a range between the dates I mentioned above: `fq=photo_added:[2009-12-28T18:00:00Z TO 2010-01-28T18:00:00Z]`

Comment: It sucks how you have to add additional logic to get the facet that you already specified with date.start, date.end and date.gap. There's a feature request to fix this behaviour here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-1896